# WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render Unable to expand length of this stream beyond its capacity

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

i am using WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions and below is my code where i am getting error that "Unable to expand length of this stream beyond its capacity".

i am getting error in Render.

```
var bitmap = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(mainImage);

<Grid Name="mainImage">
                <Image Name="frameImage"
                       Source="Image/u117_normal.png"
                       Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                <Image Name="userImage"
                       Source="Image/u66_normal.png"
                       Width="700"
                       Height="500"></Image>
                <Canvas>
                    <Image Name="AddonImage"
                           Source="Image/u103_normal.png"
                           Width="100"
                           Height="100"></Image>
                </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

can anyone help me for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is in

[Frame Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx)

It states:

parameter-> the object being passed

Type: System.Object [.NET] | Platform::Object [C++]
The navigation parameter to pass to the target page; must have a basic type (string, char, numeric, or GUID) to support parameter serialization using GetNavigationState. Its an issue of serialization. Check if you can pass a supported format or try use local storage if possible :) Please update me if there's is some other concern.

Comment: No i am getting error in below line.
var bitmap = await WriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.Render(mainImage);
Please check updated question.

Comment: Ohh you got me confused... Wait let me check for it.

Comment: Yes sorry for that but i forget to mention line where i was getting error. i guess now its much clear.